# how to solve Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, gradle, exception, task

I am try to learn flutter. but in first when I want to run default app in flutter(counter) I face to this error. can you help me how I can solve it?

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode…
Running Gradle task ‘assembleDebug’…

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not connect to the Gradle daemon.
Daemon uid: 7e121133-e94a-477f-b757-cb0b2f130b5e with diagnostics:
Daemon pid: 11244
log file: C:\Users\Morteza.gradle\daemon\5.6.2\daemon-11244.out.log
----- Last 20 lines from daemon log file - daemon-11244.out.log -----
23:51:11.367 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
23:51:11.368 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000
23:51:11.371 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
23:51:11.372 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
23:51:11.375 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
23:51:11.376 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
23:51:11.380 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
23:51:11.383 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpIncomingConnector] Listening on [dcd48d42-facd-4af7-9888-10006483df5b port:65384, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]].
23:51:11.388 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] Daemon starting at: Wed Sep 16 23:51:11 PDT 2020, with address: [dcd48d42-facd-4af7-9888-10006483df5b port:65384, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]]
23:51:11.389 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonRegistryUpdater] Advertising the daemon address to the clients: [dcd48d42-facd-4af7-9888-10006483df5b port:65384, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]]
23:51:11.389 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonRegistryUpdater] Advertised daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=7e121133-e94a-477f-b757-cb0b2f130b5e,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Morteza.gradle\daemon,pid=11244,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-Xmx1536M,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
23:51:11.391 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Storing daemon address: [dcd48d42-facd-4af7-9888-10006483df5b port:65384, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]], context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=7e121133-e94a-477f-b757-cb0b2f130b5e,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Morteza.gradle\daemon,pid=11244,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-Xmx1536M,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
23:51:11.405 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
23:51:11.411 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
23:51:11.420 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
23:51:11.420 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] Daemon server started.
23:51:11.423 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonStartupCommunication] Completed writing the daemon greeting. Closing streams…
23:51:11.433 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] stopOnExpiration() called on daemon
23:51:11.435 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] awaitExpiration() called on daemon
23:51:11.435 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] daemon is running. Sleeping until state changes.
----- End of the daemon log -----

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: How were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is `flutter clean` `flutter upgrade` and `Invalidate caches and restart`. If you are using Android Studio/IntelliJ

Comment: I did that but again I got that exception, I really mixed up how I can solve it

Comment: @Morteza You can delete IDE then install again. I don't sure success but it is solution. Usually use the previous method and restart the IDE, then run normally.